# Mvc ActionResult redirect using Json on success

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to redirect users after successfully completing a form.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Acquisition acquisitions)
{
    return Json(new
    {
        redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Acquisitions"),
        isRedirect = true
    });
}
```

After adding the return Json to my controller I'm getting this error message:

> Error 6   The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Acquisitions/Create",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.isRedirect) {
            window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Does your project have a reference to `System.Web`? It should.. since it's an ASP.NET application..

Comment: Have you validated that you have the reference in your solution? Have you done a clean and rebuild (I know rebuild is suppose to do a clean).

Comment: System.Web is referenced and I tried a clean/rebuild with the same results.

Comment: Is there more than one project in your solution?

Comment: System.Web was missing. I swear it was there but I was wrong.